# file conversion vtk to obj or other format

Tags: javascript, ruby, three.js, webgl, vtk

i want to convert .vtk-files to .obj or .json.

since [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/resources/software.html) offers [vtkOBJExporter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.6/html/a01223.html) class it is possible to convert. but how do i achieve this? i installed the visualization toolkit but when i open it, there is only a console shown. how can i call the conversion method?

want i want to achieve is to call the vtk.exe from ruby and
convert all given vtk files to a file that can be displayed in a webgl canvas and i don't want to use
[xtk](http://www.goxtk.com). instead i want to use [three.js](http://www.threejs.org).

does anybody work on something like that or does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js (r49) now has a vtk loader.

Issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1721

Example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_vtk.html

Source code:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_vtk.html